# Does the Cassandra 2.1 stress tool support UDT and multiple tables

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Our `CREATE TABLE` statement uses a user defined type (the ones you create with `CREATE TYPE`). Is this supported in the stress tool in 2.1? It doesn't look that way if I look into [StressProfile.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/tools/stress/src/org/apache/cassandra/stress/StressProfile.java)

Also I was wondering if there was a way to stress test multiple tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that is not possible. While using `cassandra-stress` (2.1) I furthermore noticed that not only UDTs but the CQL data type `map` is not supported as well.

I ended up to create one user profile for each table and dropped the `map`-typed columns from the table while stressing.